# How to pass two values back to controller from DropDownListFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view that has a form to create a new database entry using entityframework.

I can get the dropdown selection to assign the `productId` value but I also need it to assign a second value which i cannot seem to get.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SerialNumber.ProductId , 
    new SelectList(Model.Products, "Id", "Name") , "Select Product",
    new { @class = "form-control", id = "productDropDownList" } )
```

How can i get this dropdown selection to fill both `productId` and `name` from one single selection?

Comment: A `select` option can have only one value.  You could perhaps combine two values into a string and then parse the string back out to the two value after it's posted.  Though perhaps stepping back and re-thinking the approach itself may also be in order here.  If you have the product ID then surely you can get the name from the backing data?

Comment: You should not need to submit the selected text. If you need it in the POST method, then get it from the database based on the value of `ProductId`

Comment: maybe if I explain this way: i want to make it so when i select a item from the dropdown list, i can change the innerHTML of two labsl to show "productId" and one to show that "productName". I can get the ID to work but cant get name. can i return a full product object then use javascript to get the indivisual elements of that object to assign to my labels?

Comment: @Christof: You could *serialize* a product object and have that be the value of the `select`, then parse what you need from that value where needed.  But I still suspect another approach is probably a better idea here.  For example, how many products are there?  Is this static data that can be loaded into the JavaScript when the page loads?  Or fetched via AJAX when the selection is made?  Based on the ID you really should be able to get the name from somewhere.

Comment: @David my viewmodel contains a list of products to fill the dropdownlist. The list populates with the product names. And as seen in my code it selects the "Id" and returns that ID when the form is submitted. What and where would i type something to make it get the "Product.Name" based on "Product.Id"?

Comment: @Christof: Depends on where you need to *use* that data.  If it's server-side, and the product data is in the database (or cached somewhere), then with that ID you can get the Product record from the data.  If it's client-side, then options would likely include either making an AJAX request to the server to get the Product record based on the ID or pre-loading all the product records into perhaps a JavaScript array and get the Product record from that array based on the ID.

Comment: @David thats exactly what i cant figure out. how do i get the other values of the product based on its ID in javascript? Ive tried a foreach statement with a if, but cant get the id value i have gotten into that foreach loop. :(

Comment: @Christof: For starters, if you're using the value in JavaScript then you definitely want to stop talking about "posting back to the controller", that's just misdirecting the issue.  Now, specifically in JavaScript how are you looking to get this value?  We've mentioned three options so far: (1) Serializing more data into the `select` options; (2) Including all product records as a JavaScript array on the page for lookups; (3) Making an AJAX request to the server to fetch the selected product record.  Which are you attempting?